# How to make procedural wood material with knots?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

Recently I saw new cycles wood shader from CG Cookie, that looks very impressive and I was wondering if it is possible somehow to mix few wave textures to achieve natural looking knots on the wood.
Here are some examples:

[image: Knot1]

[image: Knot2]

My first Attempt:

[image]

Comment: Currently I am trying to limit the amount of rings on the wave texture, once I figure out how to do that, that texture should morph with the main wave texture and placed randomly across the object. And somehow the knot  should expand from the center of the main wave texture.

Comment: Then post your node setup and/or blend file.

Comment: I added blend file with my first attempt.

Comment: The wood osl shader explained on [this page](http://www.swineworld.org/2013/07/OSL-wood-shader-with-knots-for-Blender-Cycles.html) has knots in it, if you don't want to use osl then you may get some inspiration.

Comment: I recommend taking a look at [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kAUmLcXhUj0&hd=1) from the 2014 blender conference, if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks @gandalf3, this is really good one, I wish there were more examples like that for procedural textures.

Comment: @Denis Indeed. It's quite a challenge to make procedural textures which look natural and photo-realistic..

Comment: have you tried this?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DcfPH4psKX4